# update manager in ubuntu 12.10 can't access repository, but software center can

Tags: 12.10, update-manager

For some reason, whenever I try to search for updates with Ubuntu 12.10's update manager, I always get this error: Failed to download repository information, followed by the following details:

```
W:Failed to fetch [http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg][1]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:   
W:Failed to fetch [http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/i18n/Translation-en][2]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:   
W:Failed to fetch [http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/i18n/Translation-en_CA][3]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:    
W:Failed to fetch [http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources][4]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:    
W:Failed to fetch [http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages][5]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:    
W:Failed to fetch h[ttp://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages][6]  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:    
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Initially I thought that for whatever reason the repositories were down, so I switched from the Canada server to the main server. I still got the same error. I also tried installing some things from the ubuntu software center. Funny thing is, that worked fine and I was able to successfully download and install software from the software center, so it seems that only update manager can't access the repositories.

I have searched for and found similar cases (relating to ubuntu 12.10), but most of those cases involved ppa's, and I don't use any ppa's.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a proxy, you will not be able to use the Update Manager without configuring your system appropriately.

The Ubuntu Update Manager uses the same proxy configuration as `apt-get`, the problem with this is that the system proxy setting does not alter the `apt-get` proxy setting. This must be done manually by editing `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` and add the relevant data. An example of a http proxy server is

> Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";

Make sure that your password does NOT contain any non-ASCII chars as this might create some problems due to the files encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the GNOME desktop and was having the same problem. Here's what I did:

1. I went to Administration and started Software Updater.
2. I then clicked on Stop for it to stop updating. It went to saying I canceled updating then had a tab to the left for settings.
3. I clicked on Settings the screen came up.

   - Under Ubuntu software, I unchecked everything then checked the top three under downloadable from the Internet:

     - canonical supported
     - community maintained
     - proprietary drivers (I have a video card that can use these drivers)
   - Under other software I unchecked all
   - Then checked the first two canonical partners
   - I then closed Software Sources out and then restarted Software Updater
   - I waited to see if it worked and it did
4. I made a few adjustments before doing this but the adjustments never worked.

   I went to the [web page](http://extras.ubuntu.com) that failed to load by typing in the address in the web browser I was using. I then clicked on the links to go down through the web pages the Software Updater could not go to before I changed the settings in Software Updater.
5. Then back to Other Software

   Once the Canonical sources worked under other Software, I added the other software sources one at a time then closed it out and run Software Updater.

   My other sources were:

   - independent provided by other software http://packages.medibuntu.org
   - added by software center ryzom
   - added by software center pct-listen
   - added by software center lord of ultima

   Under Update tab:

   - check only important security updates and recommended updates

   Under additional drivers I am using:

   - X.org x server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper

I am not a expert at Linux but hope this helps.